# Python SUMIF with one condition across dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, sumifs

I'm working with two dataframes

- MRP:

| Material | Description | Septiembre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1208181 | ADSV,NA,MX,ADH HOTMET 814433PM | 630.2888856 |
| 1206500 | SHWP,NA,MX,WRAP M-WRAP 18' | 459.4193011 |
| 3049172 | INSR,LUFTL,BR,LUFTAL | 0 |
| 3049173 | CLOS,LUFTL,BR,BERRY | 0 |
| 3060614 | BOTL,LUFTL,BR,LDPE/HDPE 15 ML | 0 |

- SMCalc:

| Material | Description | Brand | Available Qty | Avail. - 6mth. | sep |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0324583 | MEAS,MUCNX,US,BLUE,20ML | MCN | 921888 |  | 980554.96 |
| 0327757 | CLOS,MUCNX,US,CR24MM | MCN | 9509400 | 6219256.172 | 975724.64 |
| 1019906 | ACETAMINOPHEN DC 90 COARSE L | TEM | 43900 | -4443.531438 | 7372.2407 |
| 1020442 | ACETAMINOPHEN POWDER | NA | 64203.289 | 38020.3542 | 6784.4993 |
| 1120252 | TARTARIC ACID | PIC | 43217.08 |  | 9370.0843 |

And I'm using this formula in excel: `=+SUMIF(MRP!$A:$A,$A2,MRP!C:C)` where:

- **Range** is MRP!A:A (Material)
- **Criteria** is SMCalc $A2 (Material)
- **Sum range** is MRP!C:C (Septiembre)

The output I'm looking for is the column F in `SMCalc`.

Comment: Please don't post photos of your data.  Copy and paste it from excel into the editor and format it as code.

Comment: Please explain in plain English what you're trying to do, and please post an example of the expected output!

Comment: how would you create a new serie with this formula +SUMIF(MRP!$A:$A,$A2,MRP!C:C) ? 
What I need is to match columns A's from two diferrent data frames (MRP and SMCalc) and if they are equal, sum the column September from df MRP @Chris

Comment: I don't see any material matches between the two dataframes.  Please add a 3rd table that shows the output of running this on those two samples.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, that excel formula calculates the sum of 'Septiembre' in column C of MRP when 'Material' in SMCalc matches 'Material' in MRP...

Assuming you have both excel sheets as pandas dataframes, I would then do:

```
mrp.groupby('Material')['Septiembre'].sum().reset_index()
```

To find the sum of 'Septiembre' per material in mrc. Then merge that with the other dataframe:

```
smcalc.merge(mrp.groupby('Material')['Septiembre'].sum().reset_index(),how='left')
```

To then bring back those values to smcalc where we want them to be